# Failing to enroll new user in Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am trying to modify the balance-transfer example of hyperledger fabric to use with different org and domain instead of Org1.example.com. but when trying to enroll new user I am getting below error.

> Failed to get registered user: Jim with error: Error: Enrollment
>   failed with errors [[{"code":20,"message":"Authentication failure"}]]

when checked the ca docker logs it shows below error.

> POST /api/v1/enroll 401 23 "Failed to get user: : scode: 404, code:
>   63, msg: Failed to get User: sql: no rows in result set".

Comment: Did you successfully execute a "register" prior to attempting the enroll?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem that I fixed by going back to the config.json and undoing some of the changes I had made.  Specifically keeping "Org1": and "Org2": instead of replacing them with my specific organization names.